# Program for presenting geometry visually

Tags: geometry

So, I want a program that can be used to visually demonstrate why something works, this is vague so I will give an example of one of the features that would be great to have:

Let's say I have two circles, circle A and B, B is 3.5 times bigger than A.    [The two circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9LO1.png)

I would like to constrain the distance between the center points of the two circles so they are always the same distance apart, so I can have the circle roll around the other one, and rotate as it would if rolling a dime around a quarter.

If there is any program that is capable of this it would be great :3

Comment: Geogebra should do it.  It's the standard, and visual / GUI

Answer (score 2):

What EnjoysMath said.  Geogebra is free, open source, and intuitive.

www.geogebra.com